# Check if list range is in another list range

Tags: python, list

I want to check if a range of a list is in the range of the next list, here is an example:

```
pos = [[50, 100], [50, 200], [250, 1500], [300, 2000], [300, 3300]]
```

As we can see here, the `pos[0]` is in the range of `pos[1]` (`[50, 100]` included in `[50, 200]`), the same thing for `pos[2]` with `pos[3]` and `pos[4]` with `pos[5]`.

To do so, I created a function that returns a boolean :

```
def in_list(i): # index of the list
    if i < len(pos)-2 and pos[i][0] >= pos[i+1][0] and pos[i][0] <= pos[i+1][1] 
    and pos[i][1] >= pos[i+1][0] and pos[i][1] <= pos[i+1][1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It looks so ugly, can any one suggest another solution ?

**Edit :**

As @MKesper suggested, I should also iterate over the list entries using a loop (and maybe get a list of True/False of each position).

Comment: You probably want to iterate over your list entries with `for entry in pos:`

Comment: @MKesper, yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know that the range `[a,b]` is in a range `[c,d]` given `c <= a` and `b <= d` (so `a,b` is sandwiched between `c,d` or `c <= a < b <= d`, but we assume `a < b` always holds anyway). So you can simply use:

```
def in_list(pos,i):
    a,b = pos[i]
    c,d = pos[i+1]
    return c <= a and b <= d
```

If you want to check there is *any* such case, you can use:

```
any(in_list(pos,i) for i in range(len(pos)-1))
```

Comment: maybe you could also make `pos` an argument of the function. It's not really asked for but accessing globals isn't a good practice.

Comment: @MSeifert: yeah indeed. Because in the original question `pos` had a scope that was too broad.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, but why `any(in_list(pos,2) for i in range(len(pos)-1))` returns `False` ?

Comment: @Bilal: because you called `in_list(pos,2)` with `2`. So here it only checks that `[250, 1500]` is in `[300, 2000]`... Which is not the case since `[250,299]` is not in `[300,2000]`

Answer (score 3):

Zip/interleave the list with its shifted copy, then check that previous items are contained in the range.

One liner to compute on all elements:

```
pos = [[50, 100], [50, 200], [250, 1500], [300, 2000], [300, 3300]]

result = [all(x1 <= a  <= y1 for a in t) for t,(x1,y1) in zip(pos,pos[1:])]


print(result)
```

result:

```
[True, False, False, True]
```

(result has 1 less item of course: last item cannot qualify / isn't tested)

Maybe `all` is overkill because there are only 2 values to test so an alternative could be:

```
result = [x1 <= x0 <= y1 and x1 <= y0 <= y1  for (x0,y0),(x1,y1) in zip(pos,pos[1:])]
```

Comment: as much as I like one-liners (I generally don't like them very much) this is simply hard to understand. It's probably fast, though.

Comment: my alternative may be better because it doesn't use `all`: one less gencomp